# manipulate a string into name of a variable?

Tags: c++, naming-conventions

I'm new to programming and I have some issue with my code:
I'm not really sure how that thing is called so it's hard to google it;
But I think human being will understand what I mean:

The while loop is increased by i++ each time. In the commented line I want to express

When
i = 1 , player1.cards[j] = random;
i = 2 , player2.cards[j] = random;

```
void cardScramble()
{
  int random;
  int i = 1;
  while (i <= 4)
  {
    cout << "Card of Player " << i << " : ";
    int j = 0;
    while (j < 13)
    {
      random = rand() % 52;
      if (cards[random] == NULL)
      {
        cards[random] = i;
        cout << cardName(random) << " , ";
        /*   player(i).cards[j] = random; */
        /* That's what I'm doubt with */
        j++;
      }
    }

    cout << endl;
    i++;
  }
  return;
}
```

I tried to define it or manipulate it as a string but didn't work.
Anyone can help me on this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You have to create an array of objects to accomplish this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do it the way you are thinking of.  Instead, combine `player1` and `player2` (and any other players) into an array.  For example:

```
Player_Type player[2]; // alternatively std::array<Player_Type,2> player;
```

Then you can refer to each player using `i` like this:

```
player[i].cards[j] = random;
```

Or, if you want to start `i` at 1, then just subtract 1 from it:

```
player[i-1].cards[j] = random;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use as mentioned below. You need a structure with an array of int.

```
 struct Player
    {
        public
        int[] cards = new int[13];
    };
```

Then your while loop goes something like below

```
Palyer []player = new Palyer[4];

int random;
        int i = 1;
        while (i <= 4)
        {
            cout << "Card of Player " << i << " : ";
            int j = 0;
            while (j < 13)
            {
                random = rand() % 52;
                if (player[i].cards[random] == NULL)
                {
                    cards[random] = i;
                    cout << cardName(random) << " , ";
                     player[i].cards[j] = random; 
                    /* That's what I'm doubt with */
                    j++;
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
```

//Like the answer if it is helpful

Comment: Is it case sensitive (for the variable "Player")?

Comment: Player is struct. Later i have declared an array of struct of Palyer and named as player.